# A way to graphically display the current state of execution in the VS debugger

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

I have a tree structure that I want to debug and it only consists of nodes so it's very bothersome to trace through it in the debugger. I'm looking for a way that would let me generate a diagram of the current state, preferably configurable to my liking, so that I can quickly observe how my tree looks on any given breakpoint.

Is there a tool like this already available or am I forced to implement my diagram drawing?

Comment: Why you don't use the console for take a trace of your structures?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few options. The easiest (but will still be text based) is to write a custom class to display the information in a easier to read format and use the [`[DebuggerTypeProxy]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggertypeproxyattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute on your tree class to have it use your new custom debugger type class to have control over what is displayed in the text display for the debugger when viewing one of your custom tree classes.

The 2nd option (which will be a LOT more complicated if you want to do a fancy graphical GUI), is to create a [`Visualizer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e2zc529c.aspx). This will let you design and create a new window that could display anything you wanted, however you must "install" the visualizer in to visual studio for to work (by copying the assembly for it to `My Documents\VisualStudioVersion\Visualizers`). With enough work you could potentially create an visualizer that would let you click on the visualizer icon on one of your tree objects in the debugger and have it open a new window that could look as fancy as the [Parallel Stacks Window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd998398.aspx) and have that window display your tree object in graphical form.

---

Here is a basic example of a visualizer that uses the `TreeView` control to display the data.

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.DebuggerVisualizers;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace StackOverflowExample
{
    public interface ITreeData
    {
        ITreeDataNode Top { get; }
    }

    public interface ITreeDataNode
    {
        string Data { get; set; }
        List<ITreeDataNode> Children { get; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// A Visualizer for TreeData.  
    /// </summary>
    public class TreeDataVisualizer : DialogDebuggerVisualizer
    {
        protected override void Show(IDialogVisualizerService windowService, IVisualizerObjectProvider objectProvider)
        {
            if (windowService == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("windowService");
            if (objectProvider == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("objectProvider");

            var treeData = (ITreeData)objectProvider.GetObject();

            using (var treeView = new TreeView())
            {
                treeView.AutoSize = true;
                treeView.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

                var topNode = treeView.Nodes.Add(treeData.Top.Data);

                //Recursively populate all of the child nodes.
                PopulateNodes(topNode, treeData.Top);

                windowService.ShowDialog(treeView);
            }
        }

        private static void PopulateNodes(TreeNode node, ITreeDataNode treeDataNode)
        {
            foreach (var childNode in treeDataNode.Children)
            {
                var newNode = node.Nodes.Add(childNode.Data);
                PopulateNodes(newNode, childNode);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Build the above as a class library and place it in to `My Documents\VisualStudioVersion\Visualizers`

Then in a 2nd console application add a reference to the DLL you created and type the following

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using StackOverflowExample;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    [DebuggerVisualizer(typeof(TreeDataVisualizer))]
    [Serializable]
    public class TreeData : ITreeData
    {
        public TreeData(string topData)
        {
            Top = new TreeDataNode(topData);
        }

        public ITreeDataNode Top { get; private set; }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class TreeDataNode : ITreeDataNode
    {
        public TreeDataNode(string data)
        {
            Data = data;
            Children = new List<ITreeDataNode>();
        }

        public string Data { get; set; }
        public List<ITreeDataNode> Children { get; private set; }
    }

    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var data = new TreeData("Top Node");
            data.Top.Children.Add(new TreeDataNode("1a"));

            var middleChild = new TreeDataNode("1b");
            data.Top.Children.Add(middleChild);

            data.Top.Children.Add(new TreeDataNode("1c"));

            middleChild.Children.Add(new TreeDataNode("2a"));
            middleChild.Children.Add(new TreeDataNode("2b"));

            Debugger.Break();
        }
    }
}
```

When the debugger breaks you should see a [image: magnifying glass icon] on the watch list for `data` when you click it Visual Studio will open a new window with the control we created.

[image]

Comment: @LukaHorvat Looking at it more `EnvDTE` is the wrong way to go about it, writing a Visualizer is the correct way to do this. I have updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: @LukaHorvat because I wanted to learn more how they work I created a test project to display tree data in a visualizer, I have added my code to the answer.